# Poskening Leniently

Tags: halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, machlokes, leniencies

For situations where a Rav is searching for a lenient ruling, such as in cases of major financial loss or aguna, etc., what are the guidelines that he must follow?

Is he allowed to rule like a single minority opinion, for example, despite that halacha is normally like the Rabim?

Just trying to understand how the system of paskening leniently works.

Comment: There are klalei hapsakim on this I believe the Pri Migadim discusses this

Comment: There is something tilted פלפול בהנהגת הוראות באיסור והיתר written by the ש׳ך. It is found in Yoreh Deah right after siman 242. The title says it all.

Comment: Seems like a book can be written on this. Oh wait, the Shach already did that